# Ajax parser error

Tags: javascript, ajax

My following javascript code doesn't working and return the following message : 
parsererror
resources.php should return the following :`{"cpu":"1.12"}`
resources.php file contains :

```
<?php $load = sys_getloadavg(); echo '{"cpu":"'.json_encode($load[0]).'"}'; ?>
```

Javascript code :

```
        $.ajax({
        url : 'resources.php', //Target URL for JSON file
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        async : false,
        success : function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error : function(xhr, status){
            console.log(status);
            alert(status);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Also we need some code from `resources.php`

Comment: A more precises error description/message would be helpful. "Doesn't work" is *not* helpful (we already know that it "doesn't work", otherwise you would not be asking here).

Comment: I have added the return value from resources.php.

Comment: @user205537: Yes we can see that, but its not more helpful. You say "should return", how can we be sure? Please state the php code as well so we can see what you do there.

Comment: @Felix Kling copy the code and find the error with your self if i know where is the problem i wouldn't be asking here for a help!.

Comment: You said "it returns the following message: parsererror", but that's not actually true. It goes into the error handler, where it logs the  **status** "parsererror" (i.e. the server does not return "parsererror"). That tells you that jQuery cannot parse the returned response as JSON, hence your PHP script doesn't return valid JSON.

Comment: @feat.martin its easy i just open it in my browser! any way i have added it.

Comment: Try opening the developer tools in the browser to see the raw response in the network tab. You clearly have malformed JSON from the server side.

Comment: @Felix Kling i have added the PHP code and the return value as you see its valid JSON.

Comment: Well, as *you* can see, you get a "parsererror" hence you are *not* receiving valid JSON. Maybe you have BOM at the beginning of your file, which causes problems.

Comment: @feat.martin i have opened developer tools in my browser and network tab doesn't contain that request resources.php which should be made via ajax.

Comment: The network tab will not show old requests. Keep the network tab open while making the request.

Comment: @feat.martin yes i know that.

Comment: What you need to do is to make a dictionary object (in php that is the same an array) and add the values you need to it, and then echo the json_encode of that object. I have had issues before in php trying to manually construct JSON, even if it appears valid; probably because of BOM as @FelixKling says.

Comment: @feat.martin the following php code is working and out put `{"cpu":0.25}` but the same problem with ajax.

`<?php
$load = sys_getloadavg();
$array=array();
$array['cpu'] = $load[0];
echo json_encode($array);
?>`

Comment: Maybe do a `console.log(xhr.statusText)` or `console.log(arguments[2])` and see if you get more information about the parse error.

Comment: Just one (stupid) question: Are the paths set up correctly? Do you know that the php script is actually being invoked by the ajax call at all?

Comment: Its log the following message : `parsererror`

Comment: @feat.martin sure php script will be called via ajax that's why iam trying to do it!  yes paths are correctly the php script in the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed the header in php. can check it properly

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $load = sys_getloadavg();
    $data = array('cpu' => $load);
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

**jquery:**

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'resources.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error : function(xhr, status){
        console.log(status);
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice, so easy to forget the simple things and think too complex right away!

Comment: yeah..i saw the comment discussion and just wanted to check if it was a silly mistake.

Comment: FWIW, the header should not be necessary for jQuery at least, since you explicitly tell jQuery to expect JSON. It's still good practice to have it. It shouldn't make a difference for the problem though.

Comment: yes agreed. I copied the content from the question. Just wanted to point the main mistake.